# Is Eatable acceptable in the following statement?

Tags: vocabulary

I have encountered an exam question.
The model answer is edible.

A)The fruit is edible and its juice is made into wine.

B)The fruit is eatable and its juice is made into wine.

Is eatable acceptable in the above case?

Answer (score 0):

It's my understanding that *edible* = of a type suitable for eating.

*Eatable* = in a state fit for eating.

Comment: Covered before, but also lacking well-supported answers.

Comment: Therefore, to answer the OP directly, A is the correct answer, as the sentence is obviously about the general characteristics of this kind of fruit, rather than the condition of a particular piece of such fruit.